# How do I run docker container as exact user on host?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, volumes

On my host I have the user 'appuser', and in my dockerfile I create the user 'appuser'.

1) Lets say my program takes in a single file from /tmp/a/ and outputs a new file to /tmp/b/ which are passed as volumes to the container from the host.
2) As appuser on the host I create /tmp/a/test.txt, but the outputted file has permissions 'polkitd:libstoragemgmt' for some reason instead of 'appuser:appuser'.

How can I get make sure the outputted file will have 'appuser' permissions (same user running program inside container)?

Answer (score 2):

The user inside of the container does not exist on the host, what is shared between the two environments is the UID/GID. So inside the container, the UID may map to appuser while on your host that same UID may map to polkitd. If you look at your /etc/passwd file on the host and container, you'll see that they likely do not match. This is only really visible when you use a host mount since the file owners are visible in that scenario on the host.

One solution you could try is mounting the /etc/passwd and /etc/group from the host to the container so that you have the same users and groups on each side, but this has the downside that the image could be build with a user that does not exist on the host, or if it does exist, it may be with different UID/GID values, making the files on the filesystem owned by the wrong users.

My personal solution is to adjust the UID/GID inside the container to match the user on the host using a script I run inside my entrypoint. It compares the owner of a file or directory you mount as a volume to that of the user inside the container, and when they do not match, the container user is modified. You need to start the container as root for this, but you can drop from root to your appuser at the end of the entrypoint to run the container command (I typically use exec + gosu for this). You can find a script for this, fix-perms, along with an example in my base image repo at https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base.

Comment: For example mariadb Dockerfile image, by default it is set to root, even though it creates the `mysql` user, I extend the Dockerfile by adding the `User mysql` tag at the end. Perfect now this container is running as non-root user, but the mysql user `uid is 999 `, and mine is  `1000 `, should I modify the mysql user to be 1000? I have a big mess with this.

Comment: @jcarlosweb have a look at the fix-perms script. Just changing the uid in /etc/passwd is often not enough since files in the image often exists with the old uid, so you need to adjust file ownership as well. I tend to do it on the fly as part of container startup because today your uid is 1000 but tomorrow your coworker is 1001.

Comment: I understand, but if for example in that container I don't need host access, i.e. I'm not going to bind mount, just a name volume, could I really be ok with the uid generated by the container?

Comment: @jcarlosweb the question here it's about host volumes. If you don't have host volumes, then it sounds like you have a different question.